# How to sign message with Ledger (Phantom extension)? Or alternative solution?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, ledger

Signing message to prove the ownership of an address is a common and 0 cost solution among many apps. Most of wallet extensions support it with a provided function commonly called `signMessage`.

However, **Ledger** does currently not support sign message feature and doesn't seem to support in the near future.

**[This Github issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/issues/152)** indicates that this issue was fixed but it doesn't seem to be really fixed.

Are there any solutions to this question? or alternative approaches to prove ownership of the wallet through **Ledger**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Ledger signing is available in the Ledger Solana app v1.3, but it didn’t seem to be available yet last time I checked.

What you can do is build/sign a transaction in the client then serialize and send to the backend. Backend can then deserialize and verify the expected wallet signed it.

More details here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/21366#issuecomment-1194310677

Comment: It s working just fine. A pretty good solution even though it doesn't feel really safe to just use a signed but not sent transaction. 

Let's hope wallet adapter package implements the support for it.

Answer (score 3):

Off-chain message signing feature is indeed included in the Ledger Solana app v.1.3.0. While the work on the app itself and corresponding libraries/command line tools have been completed, it takes some time for Ledger devs to perform the formal audit of the changes and make the app available in Ledger Live. The last time I asked, I was given an ETA of December 5th.

Comment: Oh, that sounds actually good and close. I don't close to follow how accurate ETAs of Ledger app but, next couple of weeks at least. Thank you for informing.

Comment: Any news on this? I still haven't seen v1.3 show up on Ledger Live (version 2.51 as of this comment).

Comment: The Ledger team apologized for the delay, they say an audit takes longer than expected. The new ETA that I was given on Dec 20 is early 2023, whatever it means. I'll ask them next week for an update.

Comment: @ASkibin Any update on this?

Comment: @KeithWalton this is the current state of things: off-chain message signing was released back in Jan according to the original spec: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e80f67dd58b7fa3901168055211f346164efa43a/docs/src/proposals/off-chain-message-signing.md
Docs: https://docs.solana.com/cli/sign-offchain-message

Comment: @KeithWalton But the spec was deemed incomplete and was later updated to include new features like the list of signers in the message.
New spec: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/docs/src/proposals/off-chain-message-signing.md
The Ledger app hasn't been updated per the new spec, and when it does, there is no guarantee that the old version will still be supported. The Foundation is taking over Ledger development so it might go more smoothly in the future.